# Does NetApp providing tooling to export a WAFL export snapshots to a file?

Tags: backup, storage, snapshot, netapp

With the open source ZFS file systm, an exact copy/snapshot can be produced using `zfs snapshot`. This includes file-system level optimizations like deduplication. Further you can send these to a remote server that's listening with `zfs receive` using `zfs send`.

Can something similar be done with NetApp's WAFL? At the least I want to create a snapshot and export it to a file which I can transfer to another ONTAP instance and restore with.

Comment: With WAFL you'd need a whole chain of these backups just to get a coherent filesystem, and restore them in order.

Comment: read up on copy-nahostfile this may give you a hint as to what you need to do.  copy-nahostfile is only a powershell commandlet for now but.

Comment: what version of ontap do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only approach from a NetApp perspective is to run SnapVault between your primary and secondary (in NA lingo).

Comment: Is this still true?

Answer (score 2):

"Export" is the wrong word. You can clone it onto disk, replicate it onto another filer, or copy it (like any other file) onto another non-WAFL server. You could also create a read/write copy that initially only takes the space already taken by the original data.

That said, assuming you're trying to back up a snapshot, your best choice would to be to use backup software that supports NDMP.

Comment: That very interesting! Do you have links on how to copy a snapshot to another non-WAFL server? Or perhaps the commands involved?

Comment: Assuming it's not a disk volume (block IO), you would simply mount the snapshot on the target server and use an operating system command to copy it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [ndmpcopy](https://docs.netapp.com/us-en/ontap/tape-backup/transfer-data-ndmpcopy-task.html)

It will copy data between Netapps, without using temporary files.